# prompt возвращает NaN

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь сделать простой deposit calc. С числами он работает нормально, но если ввести вместо числа строку то вернет NaN. Не понимаю что не так, я же перед prompt указала parseInt(), почему код не преобразовывает строку в число?

https://codepen.io/kosh3n/pen/LYdgRyJ

```
let init = parseInt(prompt('initial amount of money')); 
const initMin = 1000;

let years = parseInt(prompt('number of years')); 

let percentage = parseInt(prompt('percentage of a year')); 
const percentageMax = 100; 

const magicNum = 0.01;
const interest = percentage * magicNum;

function fits(years) {
  if (Number.isInteger(years) !== true) {
  alert('Invalid input data');
}
}

const result = Math.pow(1 + interest, years);
const totalAmount = Math.floor(init * result);
const totalProfit = totalAmount - init;

alert('Total profit: ' + totalProfit);
alert('Total amount: ' + totalAmount);
```

Comment: `NaN` - Это вполне себе число. Какую строку ты вводишь?

Comment: а зачем ты вводишь вместо числа строку? parseInt не обязан преобразовать строку в число, он это делает по возможности.

Comment: Ввожу числовую строку, например "1000" вместо 1000 и он выводит NaN, а мне нужно чтобы код работал вместе со строкой, то есть переводил string в number. В смысле "parseInt" не обязан переводить в число, в mdn же написано что переводит, там нет что "иногда переводит, но не обязан") Ладно, даже если убрать parseInt, а после получения значения из prompt полученную строку умножить на 1 или использовать Number() с полученным значением, код всё равно выдает NaN и я хочу понять почему. Может кто-то объяснить?